# Running QGIS GUI in Docker Container

Tags: qgis, docker

I am trying to create container and load QGIS GUI from [qgis/qgis](https://hub.docker.com/r/qgis/qgis) docker image. But unfortunately I am faced with this error on running the following command

```
C:\Users\spa> docker run --rm -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY qgis/qgis /bin/bash
root@a51412bc8744:/# qgis
```

```
Warning: could not connect to display
Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

QGIS died on signal -1Aborted
root@a51412bc8744:/#
```

I am trying to install the plugins with `sudo apt-get eglfs` but that results in error.

There are no answers on qgis GUI running in docker container but qgis-server. So how do you run QGIS GUI application inside a docker container?

Answer (score 4):

You need to export your current user and X-window environment correctly, which including you have to using the same user id, share .X11-unix socket and .XAuthority.  Also you need to let the user have permission to its home inside docker.

The example working docker run command shows below, where assume your host user id = 1000, and home dir is set to /home/user, then you need to mount your /etc/passwd, a working folder mount as /home/user (to make the user and user home exists in the docker), also the X11-unix and XAuthority like

```
docker run --rm -it -u 1000 -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v $PWD:/home/user -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/user/.Xauthority qgis/qgis:release-3_28 /bin/bash
```

Update: you can also this command to extract user id and home dir from shell directly, which should work in most of enviroment

```
docker run --rm -it -u $UID -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v $PWD:$HOME -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $HOME/.Xauthority:$HOME/.Xauthority qgis/qgis:release-3_28 /bin/bash
```